# Regular expression for this?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I make a RegEx that matches something like these?

```
"Hi hello world" and "Hi world"
```

I tried

```
/^Hi (hello)? world$/i
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Mind the spaces between words. I don't know javasript regex syntax, but may be you should also escape some of the special characters

Comment: You made "hello" an optional capture, but now you have two spaces in a row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^Hi( hello)? world$/i
```

The space before `hello` (or the one after) also needs to be optional, otherwise it matches either:

- `hi__world` (the underscores are "spaces")
- `hi hello world`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
 /^Hi( | hello )world$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

try `/^Hi (hello )?world$/i`,
your code only match "Hi hello world" and "Hi  world"

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi (\hello |)world
```

The pipe character works as "or."  So, the expression inside the parens matches either " hello" or nothing.
You can test your Javascript regulare expressions here:
http://rejex.heroku.com/